# how do i find out if an attribute in xpath contains any value from a specific list

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

how do i find out if an attribute in xpath contains any value from a  specific list,

for example in the below case, i want to find `X/Y` , which has an attribute `A` has any value , from the list {"35","36","37"}. The output should be the third `Y` element.

```
<X>
<Y A="1" ></Y>
<Y A="2" ></Y>
<Y A="35" ></Y>
</X>
```

I am adding some more details that i require to solve my original problem. the list of values are result of another xpath expression.

```
   <X>
    <Y A="1" ></Y>
    <Y A="22" ></Y>
    <Y A="35" ></Y>
    <reference parent="X" child="Y" refid="35"></reference>
    <reference parent="X" child="Y" refid="36"></reference>
    <reference parent="X" child="Y" refid="37"></reference>
   </X>
```

the list of values which contains the possible values of `X/Y/@A` comes from `/X/reference[@parent="X"][@child="Y"]/@refid` ... Is there a way i can use another xpath expression inside `contains` function ?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @JackFleeting can i do it in xpath1.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
//Y[@A = ../reference[@parent = 'X' and @child = 'Y']/@refid]
```

---

**Original question:**

In XPath 1.0 you can use:

```
//Y[@A = 35 or @A = 36 or @A = 37]
```

or something more exotic :)

```
//Y[contains("|35|36|37|", concat('|', @A, '|'))]
```

Comment: thank you, could you please check the updated details in the question?

Comment: @DivyaMV, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

(Answering the edited question.)

In straight XPath 1.0: `/X/Y[@A = ../reference/@refid]`

The [rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#booleans) for the XPath `=` and `!=` operators
([EqualityExpr](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#NT-EqualityExpr))
are quite complex. Comparing 2 nodesets returns true if there is a
pair of nodes, one from each nodeset, that have the same string value.

---

(Answering the original question.)

With XPath 1.0 and [EXSLT](https://exslt.github.io/str/functions/split/index.html) you can say
`/X/Y[@A = str:split("35 36 37")]`
provided the `str` namespace prefix is bound to the string
`http://exslt.org/strings`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with xpath 1.0 but it's a little cumbersome since you have to break out the list in question:

```
//Y[./@A="35" or ./@A="36" or ./@A="37"]
```

Comment: thank you, could you please check the updated details in the question?

Answer (score 0):

In xpath 2.0+ it's much easier as you can test against a sequence...

```xml
/X/Y[@A=('35','36','37')]
```

or regex (which might also be possible in xpath 1.0 if extension functions are available)

```xml
/X/Y[matches(@A,'^3[5-7]$')]
```